# MonoGame Mac installation instructions

Tags: xna, c#, macos, monogame

Does anyone know how to install MonoGame on Mac. I have been looking around for a while and I can't find any guides. I have Mono and MonoDevelop up and running fine, but I cannot figure out how to install MonoGame.
Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing a specific piece of software, which is better suited to the support forums of the software in question.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this at their GitHub page.](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Tutorials%3aInstalling-Prerequisites-on-MacOS-for-MonoMac-project) It tells you all the things you need in advance, as well as the basic installation instructions for MonoGame itself.

Comment: I saw that link before. Im not sure what I am supposed to do after I unzip MonoGame.

Comment: It says to add it to your project. So you would make a project in whatever your IDE is (sorry, I don't have a Mac) and you would reference MonoGame within the project.

Answer (score 2):

I know its late but I just joint monogame and found the solution:
To make it work follow the following steps:

- Install the latest xamarin studio from **http://xamarin.com/studio**
- Next download the monogame files from **https://monogame.codeplex.com/releases/view/102870**
- choose the xamarin version on mac
- Next install the templates by opening xamarin studio. Next click on the top Mac menu "Xamarin Studio" Addin Manger and choose install from file and select your donwloaded file...
- so far so good but your png files will not be loaded from here... so solve this issue follow the next steps:
  visit the git page from monogame and download it: **https://github.com/mono/MonoGame**
- after Downloading and unpacking the zip file go into the folder and look open the following file by using xamarin studio
  **MonoGame.Framework.MacOS.sln**
- Now Xamarin studio should open up and include 2 Projects: Lidgren. ... and Monogame.Framework.MacOS
- on the top of Xamarin studio (besides the play button you should see **Debug** click on it and change it to **Release**
- now do a right click on the Monogame.Framework.MacOS project and build it new
- This should be done without any errors but you may get warnings... we do not pay attention on them :D
- next do you need to go again to the downloaded Monogame folder from where you opened the  **MonoGame.Framework.MacOS.sln** project.
- But this time you need to dive more deep into the folder structure: look for the following folder --> MonoGame.Framework/bin/MacOS/Release
- the files in the release folder are now your new libraries...
- You can copy this libraries where ever you want but you should know where they are because you need to add them to your new monogame project.
- Next open up Xamarin studio and create a new Monogame project by using the already installed templates...
- Choose the Monogame Mac Application Template

We are now almost done:

- Look for the reference "folder in the project tree inside of Xamarin studio" and do a right click on Monogame  to delete the reference...
- Now you need to add new references by right click on reference.
- Access the .Net-Assemblies and add your files from the  MonoGame.Framework/bin/MacOS/Release/- folder (make sure that you add all of them)

The final step now is to expand your Content folder in Xamarin studio and do a left click on the logo.png file. 
on the left side of the IDE you can find Properties. In the properties change 3rd from top to content instead of none.
If you run now the template the graphic should be loaded without any problems :D

Answer (score 0):

After installing all the prerequisites listed on [their GitHub tutorial page](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Tutorials%3aInstalling-Prerequisites-on-MacOS-for-MonoMac-project), you'll need to add the MonoGame.Framework.MacOS and Lidgren.Network.MacOS projects from the unzipped MonoGame directory to your solution. You'll then need to add MonoGame.Framework.MacOS in your project's references.

I also ran into snags when trying to set MonoGame up on a Mac. Getting a simple program up and running took a lot longer than expected. Once I got it working, I decided to post the basic template that I use for MonoGame projects on MacOS. You can [find that template here](https://github.com/danielellis/MonoGame-MacGame). It will likely have invalid links to the MonoGame projects, but those should be simple to fix.